# Excluding rows from sql operation when no entry exists for an earlier timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to sum over rows but only include values for which there exists a timestamp five minutes ago. I am using bigquery, which doesn't appear to support a timestamp_diff operation (but a datediff).

Consider the following data (mytable):

```
time (timestamp)    meter (int) value (float)
2013-07-03 07:50:00  1           3
2013-07-03 07:50:00  2           4
2013-07-03 07:55:00  1           3
2013-07-03 07:55:00  2           4
2013-07-03 08:00:00  1           3
2013-07-03 08:00:00  2           4
2013-07-03 08:05:00  1           3
2013-07-03 08:10:00  1           3
2013-07-03 08:10:00  2           4
```

The query I would like to expand upon can first be defined as:

```
SELECT time, SUM(value) AS sumValue, COUNT(value) AS obs
FROM mytable
GROUP BY time
```

The output is then:

```
time                 sumValue  obs
2013-07-03 07:50:00  7         2
2013-07-03 07:55:00  7         2
2013-07-03 08:00:00  7         2
2013-07-03 08:05:00  3         1
2013-07-03 08:10:00  7         2
```

I would like this query to be expanded so that meter 2's value is not included in sumValue for 2013-07-03 08:10:00 (so sumValue here = 3), because it did not have an entry for five minutes earlier. Another consequence of this is that sumValue for the first timestamp would be zero. The desired output would then be:

```
time                 sumValue  obs
2013-07-03 07:50:00  0         0
2013-07-03 07:55:00  7         2
2013-07-03 08:00:00  7         2
2013-07-03 08:05:00  3         1
2013-07-03 08:10:00  3         1
```

Can this be done in bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  time, 
  SUM(IF(delta = 300, value, 0)) sumValue, 
  COUNTIF(delta = 300) obs
FROM (
  SELECT time, meter, value, 
    UNIX_SECONDS(time) - LAG(UNIX_SECONDS(time)) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY meter ORDER BY time) delta
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY time
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from  your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 07:50:00' time, 1 meter, 3 value UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 07:50:00', 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 07:55:00', 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 07:55:00', 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 08:00:00', 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 08:00:00', 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 08:05:00', 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 08:10:00', 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-07-03 08:10:00', 2, 4 
)
SELECT 
  time, 
  SUM(IF(delta = 300, value, 0)) sumValue, 
  COUNTIF(delta = 300) obs
FROM (
  SELECT time, meter, value, 
    UNIX_SECONDS(time) - LAG(UNIX_SECONDS(time)) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY meter ORDER BY time) delta
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time
```

result is

```sql
time                        sumValue    obs  
2013-07-03 07:50:00 UTC     0           0    
2013-07-03 07:55:00 UTC     7           2    
2013-07-03 08:00:00 UTC     7           2    
2013-07-03 08:05:00 UTC     3           1    
2013-07-03 08:10:00 UTC     3           1
```